# Axios.get repeating base URL twice

Tags: javascript, string, axios, base-url

I'm trying to use `axios.get()` to access the backend of a site and returns  `JSON`. However the **server returns:**

```
GET http://philosofound.com/philosofound.com/questions 404
```

The **actual .get() call:**

```
  getQuestion() {
  axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: '/questions'
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  }
```

I tried setting the base URL to an empty string as well as the site itself, but neither has resolved the problem. I'm unsure what else to try.

Comment: somewhere in your code has set baseUrl I guess

Comment: did you try using `axios.get('/questions').then()` ?

Comment: have you overridden the axios instance ?

Comment: @Justice We had that initially and it had the same problem. We switched the syntax hoping it would solve the issue but it didn't.

Comment: @AbdelkarimELAMEL I'm not sure what you mean so I would guess that I haven't.

Comment: Take a look at this [Cheat Sheet](https://kapeli.com/cheat_sheets/Axios.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index)

Comment: Do you maybe need to rebuild your assets to deploy the changes you've made to your base-url? as in: does you project have a src & a dist directory & are the changes not getting moved from src to dist when you make them?